# Windows App Certification Kit error "The binary WinRTXamlToolkit.dll is built in debug mode."

Tags: c#, dll, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I ran Windows App Certification Kit for my Windows Store App and it failed due to following error.

"The binary WinRTXamlToolkit.dll is built in debug mode."
How do I get the DLL in release mode?

I have used Nuget pakage manager to install
[PM> Install-Package winrtxamltoolkit]

Here is an attached image of the error message 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried going to the build configurations in the build menu and made sure all the item listed are set to release?

Comment: build configuration does not concern imported dll references.

Comment: Then obtain a new nuget package but using the VS GUI instead of the command line utility.

Comment: try this: Download the source code for WinRTXamlToolkit library and then add it to your solution. Now you can explicitly set it to release.